# highlightjs not working correctly with Showdown and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highlight.js, showdown

I'm trying to combine these libraries with AngularJS:

- ng-showdown
- angular-highlightjs

ng-showdown works correctly and highlightjs works for static model,
what I'm trying to achieve is do markdown syntax highlight on change dynamically so on every change on the dynamic model hljs applied again.

This plunker shows the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/062m5wzb/1/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl as vm">
  {{name}}
  <textarea ng-model="vm.notworking"
  style="width: 50%; height: 30vh;">
  </textarea>
  <br> Dynamic
  <p markdown-to-html="vm.notworking" hljs hljs-source="vm.notworking"></p>
  Static
  <p markdown-to-html="vm.working"></p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize', 'ng-showdown', 'hljs'])
  .controller("Ctrl", function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.working =
      `
\`\`\`javascript
function hello() { 
  alert('Hello world!'); 
}
\`\`\`
`;
    vm.notworking =
      `
\`\`\`javascript
function hello() { 
  alert('Hello world!'); 
}
\`\`\`
`;
  });
```

I got through documentation of angular-highlightjs but nothing seems to work for me.
https://github.com/pc035860/angular-highlightjs

I guess I am missing the on change event when it comes down to reapply highlightjs.

Comment: It seems to work correctly if you remove `markdown-to-html` from the element ([example](https://jsfiddle.net/tq9efh6d/)).

Comment: this is not possible we want the directive otherwise the rest of the md wont work i think but good point there